# Svelte CSS styling not applied to component?

Tags: css, svelte

I can't seem to correctly apply a CSS style to a Svelte component...

This is my component Svelte code:

```
<div class="slider knob"/>
<script>
</script>
<style>
       .slider::before {
            background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgb(53, 53, 53) 0%, rgb(36, 36, 36) 100%);
            width: 10em;
            height: 10em;
            border-radius: 50%;
            box-shadow:
                0px -20px 20px rgb(75, 75, 75),
                0px 20px 35px rgb(11, 11, 11),
                inset 0px 5px 6px rgb(100, 100, 100),
                inset 0px -5px 6px rgb(22, 22, 22);

        }

        .slider::before,
        .knob {
            width: 10em;
            height: 10em;
            position: relative;
            transform: rotate(calc(var(--rotation) * 1rad));
        }

        .slider::after {
            width: 10em;
            height: 10em;
            position: relative;
        }

        .knob::before,
        .knob::after,
        .slider::before {
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            border-radius: 50%;
        }


        .knob::before {
            top: 15px;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translateX(-50%);
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
            background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        }

        .knob::after {
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            width: 25px;
            height: 25px;
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
            border: 3px solid rgb(200, 200, 200, .5);
            width: 130%;
            height: 130%;
        }

</style>
```

When I load the knob and CSS in plain old HTML file it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PP56.png)

But when I load it as part of a Svelte component like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ce9Vg.png)

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Your .slider::after is missing `content: "";` Your CSS styles are too disseminated without a valid purpose, that's why it was hard to spot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<div class="slider knob"/>` That's one element with two classes. In the CSS this element is selected with either `.slider::before` or `.knob::before`, but that apparently doesn't create two pseudo elements, but the later occuring rule will overwrite the first. When changing to two elements

```
<div class="slider" />
<div class="knob" />
```

it looks closer to the first image [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/57422077b89c4ac0bd696031826ed586?version=3.58.0)

```
<div class="slider"></div>
<div class="knob"></div>

<style> 
    .slider::before {
        background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgb(53, 53, 53) 0%, rgb(36, 36, 36) 100%);
        width: 10em;
        height: 10em;
        border-radius: 50%;
        box-shadow:
            0px -20px 20px rgb(75, 75, 75),
            0px 20px 35px rgb(11, 11, 11),
            inset 0px 5px 6px rgb(100, 100, 100),
            inset 0px -5px 6px rgb(22, 22, 22);
    }

    .slider::before,
    .knob {
        width: 10em;
        height: 10em;
        position: relative;
        transform: rotate(calc(var(--rotation) * 1rad));
    }

    .slider::after {
        content: '';
        width: 10em;
        height: 10em;
        position: relative;
    }

    .knob::before,
    .knob::after,
    .slider::before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        border-radius: 50%;
    }

    .knob::before {
        top: 15px;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    }

    .knob::after {
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        width: 25px;
        height: 25px;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
        border: 3px solid rgb(200, 200, 200, .5);
        width: 130%;
        height: 130%;
    }
</style>
```

Maybe you can solve the rest from here since there's probably a container element missing
(I wonder if there's an advantage doing this with `::before` and `::after` instead of just `divs` selected with an explanatory class on it...)

Comment: You don't need closing tags in Svelte, it's compiled and normalized.

Comment: Thanks @Corrl That is enough to get me started.